# gem kaminari で undefined method `page' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`` undefined method `page' for <Article::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007ffabcd88560> `` というエラーが出力されます。

Gemfileでkaminariをインストールした後、コントローラーに以下を記述しました。

```
@asc_avg_star = Article.order('avg_star ASC').page(params[:page]).per(2)
```

記事をそのお気に入りの平均を昇順で表示させようとしています。
ググりましたが、解決に結びつきません。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 情報が不足しています。エラーのスタックトレースを追記してください。また、`@asc_avg_star`を使っているviewのコードをも追記してください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Article.all.page(params[:page])`でまず`page`メソッドが使えるかを確認してみてください。

あと`rails server`の再起動はされましたか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！
`@page = Article.all.page(params[:page])`で、pageメソッドが通りました！
しかし、viewの
`<%= paginate @page %>`がうまくWeb上に反映されない状態です。。

Comment: 「うまくWeb上に反映されない状態」というのがこちらにはわからないので、エラーのスタックトレースとviewのコードが必要です。